# How to copy paste an activity in K2 Five workflow designer

Tags: k2, k2-blackpearl

In K2 4.7 Workflow designer, we have an option to copy paste an activity. But in K2 Five we couldn't do as same?

Do we have option to do it? If yes, how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It is now available in K2 5.1, enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

It is currently not available as per the post in K2 Ideas page and it is planned to enhance in future.

Copying the note here:
*New workflow designer, add an option to copy & paste workflow nodes 
K2 Five Development team has confirmed that the copy/paste functionality does not exist for Version 1 of the new Workflow Designer.
I suggest to implement it in the next version of the new Workflow Designer.*

If you have login to K2 Portal, check the link for the update: https://ideas.k2.com/ideas/APIT-I-390